# What does “playus nigh” mean in Cockney?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, shakespeare

Quotation from *[A history of the cries of London ancient](http://archive.org/details/historyofcriesof00hind)* (p23).
Refer to *[What does “him as writ plays” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106865/what-does-him-as-writ-plays-etc-mean-in-old-newspaper-clipping)*
[image]

Comment: A playhouse near there?

Comment: It is difficult to see why this anonymous informant should manage to refer to the Bard's dwelling as an _'ouse_ just after adopting a very different pronunciation for _playhouse_.

Comment: @Fortiter Because in London the term *playhouse* was the original generic term; *The Theatre* was the name of a specific playhouse, built by James Burbage in 1576. When *theatre* was adopted in polite and literary uses, *playhouse* remained in the vernacular and, without orthorgraphic reinforcement, underwent ordinary reduction, like *bosun*, or *grindstone*, which is reported as /'grɪnstən/ in Appalachia.

Comment: @Fortiter - I offer this explanation.  "playhouse"  is stressed on the first syllable. The second syllable of playhouse" is de-stressed and therefore sounds closer to a schwa. However, in the word " 'ouse", there is one stressed syllable.

Answer (score 4):

I think it means "*a theater is near there*". [mplungjan](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2022/mplungjan)  is correct about playus being playhouse.

> **"*Yes, platypus doesn't really fit the bill.*"** – Edwin Ashworth
>
> **"*I guess I should have posted as an answer then...*"** – mplungjan

Comment: Yes, _platypus_ doesn't really fit the bill.

Comment: I guess I should have posted as an answer then...